# Problem with buttons exceeding the Panel (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm having a problem with a layout I'm trying to do in java. I have 2 panels in a 800x600 frame. The first panel "gamePanel" is (600x600) and the second "menuPanel" is (200x600).

In the menuPanel there are 4 buttons that I tried to organize as a single column of 4 rows using gridLayout(which partially worked). The buttons appear to be in place but when hovering on them they expand occupying the other panel (gamePanel). I tried placing them using setBounds but they directly disappear.

[This is how it works before hovering the buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ERz9.png)
[After hovering 2 buttons, but all 4 are displayed the same way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4jX.png)

Here is the code:

```
public class Layout {
    Point point = new Point();
    public Layout() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/icon.jpg");
        
        //JFRAME 
        window.setSize(800,600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setTitle("Arkanoid");
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        
        
        //PANELS
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gamePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        menuPanel.setBounds(600,0,200,600);
        menuPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        
        window.add(gamePanel);
        window.add(menuPanel);
        
        //Buttons
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close Me");
        closeButton.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        menuPanel.add(closeButton);
        
        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        menuPanel.add(playButton);
        
        JButton Button1 = new JButton("Test1");
        menuPanel.add(Button1);
        
        JButton Button2 = new JButton("Test2");
        menuPanel.add(Button2);
        
        //Labels
     

        //SHOW
        window.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager is resetting the bounds of each component to follow the rules of the layout manager which by default for the content pane of the frame is the BorderLayout. You don't specify a constraint when adding the components to the frame, so be default they are added to the CENTER. However, a BorderLayout will only support a single component in the CENTER so the issue you see is as a result of you trying to play with the bounds of the panel yourself. Don't use setBounds(). Use proper constraints for the BorderLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which I used to place the two `JPanels`.

I added a `main` method so I could run the GUI.  I commented out the icon code, which doesn't make any sense for an undecorated `JFrame`.  I moved the  `setLocationRelativeTo` method to after the `pack` method, so the `JFrame` is actually centered.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ExampleLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExampleLayout();
            }
        });
    }

    Point point = new Point();

    public ExampleLayout() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
//      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/icon.jpg");

        // JFRAME
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Arkanoid");
        window.setUndecorated(true);
//      window.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        // PANELS
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        menuPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 600));

        window.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        // Buttons
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close Me");
        closeButton.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        menuPanel.add(closeButton);

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        menuPanel.add(playButton);

        JButton Button1 = new JButton("Test1");
        menuPanel.add(Button1);

        JButton Button2 = new JButton("Test2");
        menuPanel.add(Button2);

        // Labels

        // SHOW
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain the issue and making a working code! About the icon, I wanted it to appear in the taskbar, that's why. I will take a look at the documentation as you said!